# Jersey : How to prevent Conflicting URI templates with other web services in the same web app

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jersey

I am trying to introduce Jersey web service into a web application that has other web services (such as Apache CXF in it) in it. So I added Jersey servlet to my web.xml..

```
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
             com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.freedomoss.crowdcontrol.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

During intiliazation this servlet gives the following error about conflicting URL templates...

```
INFO: Registering Spring bean, restApiService, of type com.mycompany.ws.RestApiService as a root resource class
Mar 12, 2015 11:07:42 PM   com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
 SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
 SEVERE: Conflicting URI templates. The URI template / for root resource class com.mycompany.ws.RestApiService and the URI template / transform to the same regular expression (/.*)?
```

When I look in the code of this RestApiService, I see..

```
@Path("/")
@Service
public class RestApiService extends AbstractRestService {
```

Since this other web service is being used elsewhere in the application I cannot change the value of 'Path' although doing so does solve my problem

What else can I do? Can I somehow tell Jersey Servlet not to register this other web service "as a root resource class"?

My goal is to make Jersey work along with this other web service and not change the latter in any way.

Comment: A quick question, what should be your target URL for `RestApiService ` and do you have some other servlet with `/service/*` URI pattern?

Comment: There is also a cxf servlet in the web.xml and this is used for that RestApiService, it listens on a different url pattern as follows...   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServletSoap</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServletSoap</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Here, it happend after I included `swagger-jersey-jaxrs`.